# How to do I prevent duplicate entries for opportunity products

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I have opportunity products which have ad position, product name and date (from and to), I want to ensure that if any entry matches all three data items than it should not be saved, at least one item should be different.

How can i do that.

Answer (score 2):

Validation rule won't help because it can't look into other records, only current one (ok, it can go "up" with dot notation or a VLOOKUP function is special... but to use VLOOKUP you'd need to modify OppLineItem's Name field and it'd have to be a custom object so no cookie).

You need a helper text field marked as unique + a workflow / process builder to populate it based on some formula. That way it becomes database's job to protect the uniqueness - and that's exactly what they're good at. Don't overcomplicate it with val. rules, triggers...

Formula will probably look like `OpportunityId ' ' + Product2Id + ' ' + From__c + ' ' + To__c`. Experiment with it a bit, think whether you really need to protect against identical product names or ids (if names - make the formula sufficiently long, Name can be up to 80 characters). Workflow can fire every time or you can enhance it a bit with `ISNEW() / ISCHANGED()`.

Once you're happy with the way unique field protects your new Opportunities - check if you need a data fix to update all existing data.

Comment: Yes. I didn't knew that Opportunity and Person accounts are not supported for duplicate and matching rules +1.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to restrict user to enter duplicate values as per your requirements:-

1)Create a new field as 'Check_Duplicate_CustomName' as text type with max length. (Refer screenshot)

2)Mark it as unique value (Do not allow duplicate values).(Refer screenshot)

3)Now create a workflow rule on same object and create an action that sets the 'Check_Duplicate_CustomName' value to the combination of this

> ad position, product name and date (from and to)

Do not forget to activate this rule.
Now if u try to create new opportunity this will raise error on duplicate inputs.

[image: Workflow rule to check duplicate]

[image: create a field as unique]